# Let V be an n-dimensional complex vector space and let $T\in \mbox{End}(V)$ satisfy $E^2$ = E

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be an n-dimensional complex vector space and let $E\in \mbox{End}(V)$  satisfy $E^2 = E$. Show that there is an $r \geq 0$ and a basis$(v_1, v_2, ..., v_n)$ for $V$ such that
$E(v_i) = \begin{cases}
v_i & \text{if } 1 \leq i \leq r \\
0 & \text{if } r + 1 \leq i \leq n
\end{cases}$

Comment: Be careful with your writing: is $\;T=E\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo Thanks, I didn't notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Show $V=\ker T\oplus\operatorname{Im}T$.

Note this is true for a vector space over any field, not merely $\mathbf C$or $\mathbf R$ .

Comment: I have proven your hint. Is this all I need to do or is there more?

Comment: Only some words to conclude, if you didn't do it. $E$ is the projection onto the second factor.